# How to log artifacts in wandb while using saimpletransformers?

Tags: nlp-question-answering, simpletransformers, wandb

I am creating a Question Answering model using [simpletransformers](https://simpletransformers.ai/docs/qa-specifics/). I would also like to use wandb to track model artifacts. As I understand from [wandb docs](https://docs.wandb.ai/guides/integrations/other/simpletransformers), there is an integration touchpoint for simpletransformers but there is no mention of logging artifacts.

I would like to log artifacts generated at the train, validation, and test phase such as train.json, eval.json, test.json, output/nbest_predictions_test.json and best performing model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently simpleTransformers doesn't support logging artifacts within the training/testing scripts. But you can do it manually:

```
import os 

with wandb.init(id=model.wandb_run_id, resume="allow", project=wandb_project) as training_run:
    for dir in sorted(os.listdir("outputs")):
        if "checkpoint" in dir:
            artifact = wandb.Artifact("model-checkpoints", type="checkpoints")
            artifact.add_dir("outputs" + "/" + dir)
            training_run.log_artifact(artifact)
```

For more info, you can follow along with the W&B notebook in the SimpleTransofrmer's README.md

Comment: The referred notebook - https://colab.research.google.com/github/wandb/examples/blob/master/colabs/simpletransformers/SimpleTransformersQA.ipynb